# AFNetworking pod is in iOS project but how to link with the WatchApp Extension

Tags: ios, watch

I have `AFNetworking` *pod* installed in my **iOS Project**, But when i tried to  `import AFNetworking.h` in *watch kit app* its giving *file not found error*.

Comment: Have you tried with #import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h> ?

Comment: Yes, I tried with  #import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>  this as well still same error..